# How to generate date series in BigQuery and fill zeros for missing sales data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tried several approaches to get the desired output below

```
date         | sales
-------------+------
2021-04-01   |   128
-------------+------
2021-04-02   |   0
-------------+------
2021-04-03   |   234
-------------+------
2021-04-04   |   188
-------------+------
2021-04-05   |   432
-------------+------
2021-04-06   |   262
-------------+------
2021-04-07   |   0
-------------+------
```

At first I've generated a table `days` in BigQuery that has the following schema

```
day
-------------+------
2021-04-01
-------------+------
2021-04-02
-------------+------
2021-04-03
-------------+------
2021-04-04
-------------+------
2021-04-05
-------------+------
2021-04-06
-------------+------
2021-04-07
-------------+------
```

My sales table has the following schema

```
transaction_id  STRING  
location_id STRING  
date_local  TIMESTAMP   

date_local                     |     transaction_id                     |  location_id
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------
2021-04-01 13:02:58 UTC        |   55a99f8d-c9fe-4aa0-8a1f-9b193369883a | 164
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------
2021-04-03 21:22:27 UTC        |   19518c8d-9a6b-46a6-a509-81b4452fe94f | HARBOR1
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------
2021-04-04 05:17:10 UTC        |   220419a8-8cf9-4404-9394-f341a394fb10 | 5513
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------
```

I've tried this query

```
SELECT day,count(transaction_id) as sales FROM days AS A
LEFT JOIN sales AS B
ON A.day = DATE(B.date_local)
WHERE DATE(B.date_local) BETWEEN "2021-04-01" AND CURRENT_DATE() AND location_id = '164' GROUP BY day ORDER BY day
```

but still get a result like this

```
day            sales
-------------+------
2021-04-01   |  1
-------------+------
```

It's missing all the other dates in April.

I was assuming NULL values for the sales column after I left joined the sales table.

Am I completely on the wrong track? It would be great if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the left join with tables `days` and `sales` correctly set, but your where part will filter only the rows based on date in sales table (B.date_local). This date will be null if there is no sales transactions for that day.

Change your where part to filter on `day` -field from `days`-table. This will at least bring the days with zero sales to your result. The changed where clause would be like this:

```
...
WHERE DATE(A.day) BETWEEN "2021-04-01" AND CURRENT_DATE() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing  `AND location_id = '164'`

Comment: This doesn't not work, because I need to filter by location_id and trying to get this type of result 

`day             location_id         sales
----------------+---------------+---------
2021-04-01      | 164           | 1
----------------+---------------+---------
2021-04-02      | 164           | 0
----------------+---------------+---------
2021-04-03      | 164           | 0
----------------+---------------+---------
2021-04-04      | 164           | 0
----------------+---------------+---------
2021-04-05      | 164           | 3
----------------+---------------+--------
`